# Unexpected behavior with compound types

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I have 3 traits

```
  trait A
  trait B
  trait AB extends A with B
```

and a method

```
def collect[E: Manifest](list: List[Any]) =
    list flatMap {
      case record: E => Some(record)
      case _         => None
    }
```

For the given list

```
val list = new A {} :: new A {} :: new A with B {} :: new AB {} :: Nil
```

I invoked `collect` with different types

```
collect[A with B](list) // collect all elements from the list
collect[AB](list) // collect only the last element
```

Could anyone explain the difference in behavior for `A with B` and `AB` types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *highly unintuitive* but it conforms to the specification. First, quoting from the [Manifest docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/reflect/Manifest.html) (emphasis mine):

> A Manifest[T] is an opaque descriptor for type T. Its supported use is to give access to the **erasure** of the type

So in `collect[A with B]` we are matching the *erasure* of `A with B`. And what is that? if we look at the [Type erasure](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#type-erasure) section of the spec, we read:

> The erasure of a compound type *T1 with ... with Tn* is the erasure of the intersection dominator of *T1, ..., Tn*

and the *intersection dominator* is defined as (again, emphasis mine)

> The intersection dominator of a list of types *T1, ..., Tn* is computed as follows. Let *Ti1, ..., Tim* be the subsequence of types *Ti* which are not supertypes of some other type *Tj*. If this subsequence contains a type designator *Tc* that refers to a class which is not a trait, the intersection dominator is *Tc*. Otherwise, the intersection dominator is **the first element** of the subsequence, *Ti1*

In our case the subsequence is `A,B` as they don't have any subtyping relationship, and thus the erasure of `A with B` is `A`, so that  in `collect[A with B]` we are actually matching `A`.

You can easily see this behavior by looking at the output of `collect[B with A]`, and/or adding a `new B {}` to your `list`.