# scala cast incompatible type without throwing error

Tags: scala, types

Scala version 2.13

Update:
I think `t` cannot be cast to `A with B` since `t` cannot be `B`.

---

Like the code below.

`t` is created without any exception at runtime, which is not expected.

`a` cannot be type `B`.
The printed out `(false, false)` also shows that.

```
  class Base

  class A extends Base {
    override def toString: String = "obj A"
  }

  trait B extends Base {
    override def toString: String = "obj B"
  }

  type t1 = A with B

  val a = new A

  val t = a.asInstanceOf[t1]

  println(a,t)
  println(a.isInstanceOf[t1], a.isInstanceOf[B])
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't get it.

Comment: I think that his question is why `asInstanceOf[A with B]` does not throw exception when invoked on type `A`. I think that here some runtime magic is involved as `B` is trait here. For example explicitly calling `t.toString` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why there is an answer disappeared, but it explained the reason. I restate it here.

It is quite similar to

[Unexpected behavior with compound types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260644/unexpected-behavior-with-compound-types)

It's the Type Erasure in Scala, which is explained at

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#type-erasure

In this case the first class which is not a trait is `A`, `A with B`  will be considerred as `A`.